# Array key with the dash php 5

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key, getopt

In my code in php 5 I need to access array key which have a dash in its name(case-ins). Is there any way to do that?

My code looks like this:

```
 $count = 0;
 foreach($par as $key){
      foreach($key as $case-ins)
           $count = $count+1;
      ....   
 }
```

Basically I need to get array size. I know I can probably use the count function, but right now the biggest problem I am dealing with is the dash. I have found on the internet something like ${case-ins}. but it didn't work. I can't change name of array key because it is actually argument from command line which I got using getopt.

Could you please help me with this? Or is there any other way around to count how many times was same argument used?

Thank you for all the answers :)

Comment: `$case-ins` in that case is your choice. That is just the variable name, not the key itself. In fact, it wouldn't even be the key, it would be the value. (`foreach($arr as $key => $value)`)

Comment: Besides: `$a = array('foo-bar' => 'b'); 
echo $a['foo-bar'];` will output `b`. I think you are confusing yourself here. The `$case-ins` is the variable name. I might've understood it incorrectly, of course

Comment: @Anant I cannot use count($par) because I need to get array size that is inside this array... For example I have this array $par that is filled with arrays $i, or $case-ins... and so on. 
I am sorry if you are stating something obvious, but I am new to php and don't quite understand.

Comment: @FirstOne I am sorry if I misunderstood but if I used => $value the type of $value would have to be string or integer, but not array again... Or am I wrong? Because if I am, I must have used it wrong way, so could you please explain it more closely? :)

Comment: @Hello_World what I meant was that you can't have a variable named `$case-ins`, it throws `syntax error, unexpected '-'`. `$a-b` would at the very least mean that you want the subtract `b` from `a`. When you type a `foreach`, you define the variable name, it doesn't matter the key nor the value. See [**the error**](https://3v4l.org/BJbbt). See [**it working**](https://3v4l.org/abQDQ).

Comment: You said: _if I used => $value the type of $value would have to be string or integer_. If you are referring to the foreach, then **no**. `$value` could be anything. Even an object. Take a look at this multi level array example: [https://3v4l.org/3pSbA](https://3v4l.org/3pSbA)

Answer (score 1):

```
$par = array(
            array(
                '0'=> 'dark-blue',
                '1'=> 'yellow',
                '2'=> 'high-color'
                ),
            );

$count = 0;
foreach ($par as $key ) {   
    foreach ($key as ${'case-ins'} ) {
        if (preg_match('#-#', ${'case-ins'} )==true) {
            $count = $count+1;
        }       
    }
}
echo $count; // count is 2 ..
```

More info: in some strict PHP systems you better use `#(.+)?-(.+)?#` instead of `#-#` 
and instead of `${'case-ins'}` you may use normal variables like `$case_ins`, not dash in PHP.